# Интернет магазин на django, целесообразность использования php-скрипта

Tags: php, python-3.x, django

Есть интернет магазин на django. Надо сделать интеграцию с СДЭК. У них на сайте я нашел виджет, но он использует PHP. Будет ли разумно устанавливать PHP одновременно с Python на убунту? Будет ли это корректно работать?

Comment: Если можете, перепишите на python. Если нет, используйте как есть

Comment: Чем вам пыхтачок не устраивает?

Comment: Пых я ни разу не юзал. На питон переписать даже интересно было бы. Ищу короткий путь, но рискую пойти по длинному.

Comment: Как временное решение можете сначала использовать php. Как перепишите на python, то сделаете неоценимую поддержку в развитие open source. Возможно, ваша библиотека появится на сайте СДЭК